# Approve deployments for a a single workflow run and environment with multiple jobs in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I have a deploy workflow that sets an environment for 3 jobs. This environment is protected by rules that requires reviewers to approve the workflow run

The workflow run asks for review on the first job that sets an environment, as expected. However, it also asks for review for the remaining jobs that also sets an environment.

I guess this behaviour is normal, but it's annoying to have to approve multiple times a workflow run for the same environment.

Is there a way to only approve once the workflow run for this single environment that has multiples jobs ?

For instance in the image below, the 2nd job has requested a review which was approved, but then it also asks review for the same environment for the next job.

For clarification, these are all reusable workflows.
[image: Workflow run with multiple deployment reviews]

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this same issue I am having?